# What significance & advantages does the OSI say about open source?

Tags: osi, fsf

At the [Philosophy of the GNU Project](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/philosophy.html), there is one page [Why we must insist on free software](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-software-even-more-important.html) which states the importance/significance and advantages of free software.

So, I want to know what OSI states/shows the importance & advantages of open source?

I can see at the mission statement at about page:

> Open source is a development method for software that harnesses the power of distributed peer review and transparency of process. The promise of open source is higher quality, better reliability, greater flexibility, lower cost, and an end to predatory vendor lock-in.

But I'm looking for the (demonstrating) topics like:

- How open source is better?
- How open-sourcing is important? or Why open source?

Comment: See your own question from several months ago: http://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2210/what-does-the-open-source-initiative-say-about-proprietary-software